# Slide Out Menu with Status Bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, xcode6.1

I'm trying to create a slide out menu similar to GroupMe, where the menu slides out and so does the status bar. I've seen a bunch of slide out menu frameworks and tutorials, but none of them seem to move the status bar.

From what I've read ([Moving status bar in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007694/moving-status-bar-in-ios-7/19011013#19011013)), you can do this by screenshotting the current screen and then positioning it on the edge, but GroupMe seems to do this without screenshotting the page.

I know they're not screenshotting it, because every now and then, the status bar will show that it's loading more data. Here are some pictures that illustarte it:

GroupMe slide out menu:

[image]

GroupMe slide out menu loading data:

[image]

And if I turn off wifi while the slide out menu is still open:

[image]

I'm not sure how they're doing this, but I do know that when you re-open up the app when the slide out menu is still open, it shows a normal status bar that quickly disappears.

[image]

Comment: Hmm very interesting. I've checked a few apps with these menus and it seems either they leave it in place (stack exchange), or assign the 20 pixels to a different color to separate it from the menu altogether (facebook)

Comment: Yeah I've seen those, but I'm curious as to how they do this

Comment: The status bar should be outside an application's sandbox - although we can still grab hold of a pointer to the `UIWindow` that contains it, so it seems. I'm not sure about the validity of that approach though, as it certainly doesn't seem like Apple gives you the right to move the status bar around any app... [see this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21826959)

Comment: Yeah I found a similar solution. And this guy's app ended up being approved for the App Store: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160833/iphone-howto-move-status-bar-with-pan-gesture