# Changing the content colour of the iOS status bar?

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there a way to change the colour of the status bar to something other than black or white?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS7 - Status bar with specific color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19834045/ios7-status-bar-with-specific-color)

Answer (score 0):

Status bar is transparent nowadays so you can fake it by drawing a rectangular view (of height 20) on the screen's top of the color you want.

For text/content color, there are no other (documented) options apart black and white.

Comment: I'm talking about the content inside the status bar, e.g. the time, battery indicator and carrier.